# Odoo: one2many field still adds record even though i raise error if zero stock on it

Tags: python, odoo

so the idea is when i change the product, it checks on the stock available on the current branch, if none, it raises error that there are no stock

expected behavior: an error is raised when no stock is available on selected product and the record won't be added to tree view if no stock available

current behavior: the error is raised when no stock is available on selected product yet the record still gets added to the one2many tree view

code below

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from docutils.nodes import line

from odoo import models, fields, api, _
from odoo.exceptions import ValidationError

class CustomTransRequest(models.Model):
    _name = 'custom.trans.request'
    _description = 'Transfer Request'
    user_id = fields.Many2one('res.users', string='Salesperson', default=lambda self: self.env.user)
    branch_from_id = fields.Many2one('custom.branch', string="From", required=True)
    branch_to_id = fields.Many2one('custom.branch', string="To", required=True)
    product_ids = fields.One2many(comodel_name="custom.trans.line", inverse_name="request_id", string="Products",
                                  required=False, )
class CustomTransLine(models.Model):
    _name = 'custom.trans.line'
    _description = 'Transfer Request Line'

    branch_from_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name="custom.branch", string="Branch", )
    request_id = fields.Many2one("custom.trans.request", string="Request ID", )
    product_id = fields.Many2one("custom.product", string="Product", required=True, )
    qty = fields.Integer(string="Qty")

    @api.onchange('product_id')
    def onchange_product(self):
        if self.product_id:
            for rec in self:
                selected_lines = rec.env['custom.branch.line'].search(
                    ['&', ('product_id', '=', rec.product_id.id), ('branch_id', '=', rec.branch_from_id.id)]).mapped(
                    'qty')
                if not selected_lines:
                    raise ValidationError(
                        _('Current branch has ZERO stock on this product, Please select an available Product'))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want record into one2many field, set `product_id=False`. And return validation dictionary.

Try with following code.

```
@api.onchange('product_id')
def onchange_product(self):
    if self.product_id:
        res = {}
        selected_lines = rec.env['custom.branch.line'].search(
            ['&', 
             ('product_id', '=', self.product_id.id), 
             ('branch_id', '=', self.branch_from_id.id)]).mapped('qty')
        if not selected_lines:
            self.product_id = False
            res['warning'] = {'title': _('ValidationError'),
                              'message': _(
                                      'Current branch has ZERO stock on this product, '
                                      'Please select an available Product')}
            return res
```